# Genymotion - Device 5.0 and above are not working

Tags: android, android-emulator, genymotion

My  System Configuration :

```
 1. RAM : 6GB
 2. Windows 7 32bit OS.
```

And I have

```
Virtualbox Version : 5.0.18
Geneymotion Version : 2.6.0
```

I am running Genymotion from last 2months and it is working fine with device below 5.0. But when I tried to Install 5.0(Device : Samsung Galaxy S6 - 5.0.0 - API 21 - 1440x2560) it is giving me error and not starting .

[image]

When I tried to start it from virtual box directly it is giving me "Kernel" related issue

[image]

Please suggest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching for a long, I have emailed the issue to Genymotion Support center.
We had a conversation over email and finally Genymotion executive shared a link which resolves my issue

> CPUs include hardware virtualization features that help accelerate
>   VirtualBox. But VT-x isn’t always enabled by default.

sharing the same link here

http://www.howtogeek.com/213795/how-to-enable-intel-vt-x-in-your-computers-bios-or-uefi-firmware/

*Hope it will help to resolve problem*